# Unión de dos tuplas dentro de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-requests

Necesito, dada una lista con dos tuplas en su interior de la siguiente manera: `list = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18)]`, crear una función que una esas dos tuplas internas de dos en dos, dando lugar a muchas más tuplas.

El resultado que deseo conseguir sería, para este ejemplo. `res = [(1, 3), (2, 6), (3, 9), (4, 12), (5, 15), (6, 18)]`

Comment: `res = list(zip(*lista))`

Comment: Gracias!, mira que era fácil, torpeza mía! ;)